# How to pick the recent file from a location where multiple files are present?

Tags: vb.net

I have a requirement to pickt the latest file from a location. Could any one help me with writing the VB code for this?

Example: I have files like below and their last modified time as below

```
1. FileDec.txt       2014/12/15 8:35 AM
 2. FileJan.txt       2015/01/19 8:34 AM
 3. FileNov.txt       2014/01/20 7:48 AM
 4. xyz.txt           2015/01/22 8:34 AM
```

I need to pick FileJan.txt from my shared path(Not xyz.txt). I can not compare file names because of other consrtaint.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`files` is supposed to be some kind of collection of `File` objects. At the end of the parsing, `bestFile` should hold the latest file's object.

```
Dim bestFile as File = Nothing
Dim latest As DateTime
For Each file In files
    If (bestFile Is Nothing) Then
        bestFile = file
        latest = File.GetCreationTime(My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(file.DirectoryName, file.Name))
    Else
        Dim fileCreatedDate As DateTime = File.GetCreationTime(My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(file.DirectoryName, file.Name))
        If (DateTime.Compare(fileCreatedDate, latest) > 0) Then
            bestFile = file
            latest = fileCreatedDate
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [File.GetCreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) will give a DateTime, based on which we can do what ever required.  Refer below code

```
Dim fileCreatedDate As DateTime = File.GetCreationTime("C:\Example\MyTest.txt")
```

Comment: Awesome #sai. I am new to VB.net and I need to implement this in SSIS. So if you can help me with picking the correct file that will be great.